# How to give two conditions for lookup field in sharepoint rest api filter

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, filter, lookup

[Screenshot of Lookup column setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USx2L.png) I am trying to retrieve data from a list containing the lookup field. I want to check values in the lookup column list. My API is -
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ApprovalMaster')/items?$select=Id,Comment,RowId,ApproverStatus,Modified,FormId/Id,FormId/ListName,FormId/FormName,FormId/Created,FormId/Status&$filter=(FormId/SubmitterId eq 1 and FormId/FormName eq 'SFO')&$expand=FormId

I have tried many combinations but nothing worked. It is giving results when I try with a single condition but it is not giving results combining the two conditions.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify like below:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ApprovalMaster')/items?$select=Id,Comment,RowId,ApproverStatus,Modified,FormId/Id,FormId/ListName,FormId/FormName,FormId/Created,FormId/Status&$filter=(FormId/FormName eq 'SFO' and FormId/SubmitterId eq 1)&$expand=FormId
```

Comment: Is there any update ? Did the modified Rest request work ?

Comment: I have tried this also...but didn't work. It is not giving any error but not showing any results either.

Comment: Can you please provide the details of the lookup column setting ? You can post a screen capture in the original question so that we can research furthur.

Comment: I have added a screenshot. Have a look.

Comment: I tested to filter FormId/FormName firstly and then FormId/SubmitterId, it works as expected, I will update the answer, please check it.

Comment: @PriyanshiBaheti, is there any update ? Have you tried the updated answer ?

Comment: Yes, I tried your updated answer and it worked.